# Print HTML with IFRAME content

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, printing

I have a HTML page like that :

```
<html>
<body>
    <h3> Hello Stackoverflow </h3>
    <iframe src="test.pdf"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to print the entire HTML page (CTRL + P in the browser), so that I can get my  Hello Stackoverflow  and the contents of my pdf file on the same page, like it was rendered on the browser

Notes :

- Files can be pdf, doc or xls
- By priority solution must work fine on Internet Explorer >= 10

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the window.print function. Something like this should work:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">
    <button>Print page</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Embed** tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp

```
<embed src="file.pdf">
```